# Corda Node vs Party Clarification

Tags: blockchain, corda

Newbie alert and just finished the Corda Bootcamp videos and a few exercises.

Something that's unclear to me is: From the minimalistic "standalone" examples, I see that that Node=Party=Single JVM Process.

Is this the way it has been designed? From going through examples, it appears to me that a Party is a person (who is identified by a certificate) and part of the network.

If we model a Party to be a Node, then how can this be dynamic (where persons could join the network at realtime)?

Also, is it crazy to model Party as a department in an organisation (like below)?

For an imaginary example:

```
PartyA = Human Resources Department
PartyB = IT Department
PartyC = Finance Department
PartyD = Executives
```

Each of these departments transact with each other (in terms of a Person's payroll record, Project financials etc).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a single Party is a Node and thus is a Single JVM Process. Each party represents one node. Adding/Onboarding a node will require the process of requesting/signing with a doorman/CA.

You could represent departments by each party which in turn becomes a node on its own. Or you could let it be a single node and control the permissions of the departments at the app level.

There's something in the roadmap for a node to represent multiple `parties` but that's still far off in the future. https://groups.io/g/corda-dev/message/469